# pentaho without database

Tags: pentaho

I'm looking for a way to pentaho authenticate the users through applicationContext-spring-security-memory.

I need that spring security uses just xml files like that for authentication and not database.

I researched on the internet too, but can not find anything.

In a simple project, it is not complicated to do this, but the pentaho has a very large structure, many modules and xmls interconnected.

Any link or tutorial, I thank you.

Comment: Why? Whats wrong with the H2 installation?  This is a lot less heavyweight than a full on DB and works entirely self contained within tomcat.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but my team will make an integration with pentaho and another system. So, we decide testing the security part of pentaho to understand how it works. 
The idea is, in the future, using our own service of authentication with our database.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I found the answer in the wiki pentaho:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Changing+to+the+JDBC+Security+DAO

although this is for jdbc, i just needed to adjust for this:

```
<beans>
  <!-- some lines omitted -->
  <import resource="applicationContext-spring-security.xml" />
  <import resource="applicationContext-common-authorization.xml" />
  <import resource="applicationContext-pentaho-security-memory.xml" />
  <import resource="applicationContext-spring-security-memory.xml" />
</beans>
```